# Mimic CRYPT_BLOWFISH with MCRYPT_BLOWFISH

Tags: php, mcrypt, blowfish, phpass

My question is how do I get the same result from mcrypt as I would get from crypt, with respect to blowfish?

I am wanting to use [the phpass framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for password hashing and verifying. Which works really well as long has you have PHP 5.3 because blowfish is included with `crypt()`.
My host is running PHP 5.2.x with the mcrypt library.

Going through the docs and googling about blowfish with crypt, it appears that the result is `'$a2$'`, the two character iteration value, `'$'`, the salt ( padded or cut to 22 characters ), then a 32 base64 string representing the hash.

My problem is I can't find explanations of the `MCRYPT_MODE_modenames` that make sense to me. And how do I feed `mcrypt()` the number of iterations I want? Or are the two functions using different forms of blowfish that dont cross translate?

Comment: The difference between 5.3 and earlier is that the earlier versions use the OS call while 5.3 has its own implementations of the algorithm. Have you checked that the OS does not support CRYPT_BLOWFISH?

Comment: I did check into that. My version of PHP doesn't support CRYPT_BLOWFISH, but it does support MCRYPT_BLOWFISH. I guess the root of my question is that I need to use code written for CRYPT_BLOWFISH, while using MCRYPT_BLOWFISH. However the docs I've found make them seem very different in implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mcrypt, and crypt() are two totally different functions. Mcrypt is two-way encryption, whereas crypt is one-way encryption. As far as I am aware crypt() is inside of php 5.2. Also, if I was you I'd just reference crypt() itself. And I'd also use bcrypt from it.

```
 $hashed_password=crypt($password_to_be_hashed,'$2a$04$saltstringhere');
```

Finally, just change the two digit cost factor inside of the two digits after the $2a$. That will allow you to change the amount of cputime that is going to be required for it. Remember it goes up logarithmically(if i remember correctly). The default value is 07.

Finally crypt_blowfish is the two-way encryption algorithm of blowfish that takes keys up to 448 bits. The blowfish inside of crypt is bcrypt, is based upon blowfish but was designed for storing passwords as it hashes them. This is known as one-way encryption.